# How can I reliably find out, if a Computer supports SATA Port Multiplier or not?

Tags: sata, port, multiplier

How can I reliably find out, if a Computer supports SATA Port Multiplier or not?

Is it booting a live linux and issuing dmesg?

Answer (score 0):

Consult the manufacturer of the motherboard, or the manufacturer of the SATA Controller if there's a separate controller in a card slot which controls the drive(s) now. You can run *dmidecode* from a Linux LiveUSB to determine the make and model of the motherboard, when you look on the *Devices | DMI* page.

However, just adding a [new SATA Controller](https://www.google.com/search?q=PCIe%20SATA%20controller) will probably yield faster drive service, as Port Multipliers [share the available bandwidth from the SATA controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_multiplier) they are attached to.